# What is returned if a boolean function fails?

Tags: java

Supposing a method:

```
public boolean setAttribute(){
  boolean returnval = false;
  object = this.getObject;                       //suppose this returns null
  for(Object obj : object.getObjectsForLoop()){  //<== this will fail
     doSomething();
     returnval = true;   
  }
  return returnval;
}
```

Now, suppose this is called elsewhere, in a procedure. Will this method fail at it's fourth line and not return anything?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: When I try it, it throws a null pointer exception. I was wondering if there were any possibilities where it would continue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will throw a `NullPointerException` instead of returning anything

Read the [Exceptions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) Trail of the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) for more info.
There's a pretty good explanation of the concept and process on this page: [**What Is an Exception?**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)

Answer (score 4):

If this fails to return a valid object:

```
object = this.getObject;
```

This won't return anything. It'll throw a NullPointerException:

```
for(Object obj : object.getObjectsForLoop()){
```

Answer (score 2):

The method will complete abruptly with a `NullPointerException`. In other words: it won't return anything.

Comment: Abrupt completion includes anything that interrupts the normal flow. This includes thrown exceptions, break statements, continue statements, even return statements.

Comment: @Nathan: Interestng. The JLS part I linked to says "An abrupt completion always has an associated *reason*, which is always a `throw` with a given value." But [§14.17](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.17) says "[...] a return statement always completes abruptly". I edited my answer to remove the mis-information.

Comment: @Nathan: I see now where I got misled: [§15.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#79448) (which I had quoted before) deals **exclusively** with evaluating expressions (which can only end abruptly with a `throw` and for no other reason).

Comment: The fact that abrupt completion can be more than just thrown exceptions can sometimes be confusing in code as well. For example: `for (;/*ever*/;) try { continue; } finally { break; }` will execute the loop only once, because the `finally` picks up the abrupt completion caused by the `continue` statement and `finally` itself causes the loop to complete abruptly.

Answer (score 2):

If object is null, the use of it in the iterator will trigger a NullPointerException - thats what you will get.

Answer (score 1):

This will result in `NullPointerException` because the `for` will attempt to obtain an iterator from a `null` object.

Comment: Right. One would not expect such naming, considering the fact that Java doesn't have pointers :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by fail.  In your case it looks like you mean `throws NullPointerException`.  In that case, the caller of setAttribute will also get the NullPointerException.  If you don't handle NullPointerException at any place this will go all the back in the stack to main and terminate your program.  If you handle NullPointerException, the catch block will be called.